# Ordering a mysql query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I have 2 tables, Pages and LinkPages.
Within Pages i have the fields:

- pageID (the identifier of the page),
- startmemberID (the id of the member that created the page),
- startDate (date the page was created).

In LinkPages I have:

- pageID (to link with the page),
- linkmemberID (member linking with the page),
- joinDate (date member linked with the page).

What sql query would i use to get all information on the pages with a particular id and then order it by the date the page was started.

I got this far:

```
SELECT * FROM LinkPages WHERE linkmemberID='MEMBERID' LIMIT 5
```

but obviously i haven't ordered them here, would i need to use a join?

Many Thanks,

Jai

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM LinkPages
INNER JOIN Pages ON Pages.pageID = LinkPages.pageID
WHERE linkmemberID='MEMBERID'
ORDER BY startDate DESC
LIMIT 5
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT lp.pageID, lp.linkmemberID, lp.joinDate
FROM LinkPages lp, Pages p
WHERE lp.linkmemberID='MEMBERID' AND lp.pageID = p.pageID
ORDER BY p.startDate DESC
LIMIT 5
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two options, either you can `JOIN` or you can use a subquery:

```sql
SELECT * FROM LinkPages WHERE linkmemberID='MEMBERID' 
ORDER BY 
   (SELECT startDate FROM Pages WHERE Pages.pageID = LinkPages.PageID) DESC
LIMIT 5
```

For good measure, here's the join:

```sql
-- be sure to use L.* here, otherwise you get all of the columns from 
-- pages as well
SELECT L.* FROM LinkPages L 
  INNER JOIN Pages P ON P.pageID = L.pageID
WHERE linkmemberID='MEMBERID'
ORDER BY P.startDate DESC  LIMIT 5
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT lp.* 
FROM LinkPages lp, Pages p 
WHERE lp.pageId = p.pageId
AND lp.linkmemberID='MEMBERID' 
ORDER BY p.startDate
LIMIT 5
```

sorry - forgot the ORDER BY ...